# How to convert a matrix to an image?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, bit-depth

As clear as title declares, question is how to convert a matrix to an image with adjusting bitdepth?

I'm creating a 5x5 matrix setting values at all cells. Like,

```
A=[.....;.....;.....;.....;.....]
```

And then using imwrite function,

```
imwrite(A, Path, 'BitDepth', 2)
```

After using this function an image file occurs in the 'Path'. When i check bitdepth of the image, it is correct (2-bit) but when i read that image i see all zeros in image data matrix.

I want to create a 2-bit depth 5x5 image file which i could define all pixel values. How do i overcome that issue?

edit:

Complete code:

```
A=[0 0 2 1 1;1 2 2 2 2;2 2 2 2 3;1 2 3 3 2;2 3 1 3 2];
imwrite(A, 'Path', 'BitDepth', 2);
I=imread('Path'); //Path is 'C:\Users\...\...\...\...\...\...\A.png'
```

And i see all zeros in I matrix.

Comment: what code do you use to read the image?

Comment: I don't read an image. I want to convert an image from which i create a matrix.

Comment: well you said "when I read that image i see all zeros"...so what do you mean by that?

Comment: Uh sorry my mistake. I assumed that you misinterpreted. It was me. I read image with imread(Path)

Comment: no problem! That's weird because I tried with random data and it works very well. Can you show all of your code so we can find the error easily?

Comment: If you read the help to imwrite you see:" _assumes the dynamic range is [0,1]_"

Comment: Yes, even though i realized that, i see bit depth is adjustable in the imwrite input value set. I'm trying to adjust 2-bit depth. How do this function make compress the range [0,1] though i adjust?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Image = mat2gray(A)` to convert your matrix A to a grayscale image. Basically `mat2gray()` will just scale the values in the matrix from 0..1

After that `imwrite(Image, 'Path.png', 'Bitdepth', 2)` works fine.

Comment: When i use mat2gray(A), values of A changes. If i ignore that and read Image after using mat2gray and change values again manually, this time imwrite function strechs values to 8-bit depth. I want to create 2-bit image, so simply it doesn't work.